# Spring Integration - How to convert received Message payload in a direct channel to a temp file

Tags: spring-integration

Requirement is that the message payload received in a particular direct channel has to be converted to a json and stored in a temporary file using the spring integration.

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd">

    <int:channel id="requestChannel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="preValidationWorkers"/>
    </int:channel>

    <task:executor id="preValidationWorkers" pool-size="6" queue-capacity="6" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

    <int:channel id="validaitonSuccessChannel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="validationWorkers"/>
    </int:channel>

    <task:executor id="validationWorkers" pool-size="3" queue-capacity="3" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

    <int:channel id="transformationSuccessChanel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="transformationWorkers"/>
    </int:channel>

    <task:executor id="transformationWorkers" pool-size="3" queue-capacity="3" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


    <int:service-activator id="requestDistributor" input-channel="requestChannel"
                           ref="personValidatorService"
                           method="validate"
                           output-channel="validaitonSuccessChannel">
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:service-activator id="requestTransformer"
                           input-channel="validaitonSuccessChannel"
                           ref="personTransformationService"
                           method="transform"
                           output-channel="transformationSuccessChanel">
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:service-activator id="requestInjector"
                           input-channel="transformationSuccessChanel"
                           ref="personSqlService"
                           method="inject">
    </int:service-activator>

    <bean id="personValidatorService"
          class="com.naveendc.taskexecutor.service.validation.PersonValidatorServiceImpl" lazy-init="true">
    </bean>

    <bean id="personTransformationService"
          class="com.naveendc.taskexecutor.service.transformation.PersonTransformationServiceImpl" lazy-init="true">
    </bean>

    <bean id="personSqlService"
          class="com.naveendc.taskexecutor.service.sql.PersonSqlServiceImpl" lazy-init="true">
    </bean>

    <int:gateway id="personGateway" service-interface="com.naveendc.taskexecutor.service.integration.PersonGateway"></int:gateway>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <int:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.naveendc.taskexecutor.service, com.naveendc.taskexecutor.service.integration"/>

</beans>


Service activators method is something like this.
 @Override
    public void inject(Person person) {
        System.out.println("Person injected ==>" + person.toString()));
        return;
 }
```

Is there a way to convert the payload received in transformationSuccessChannel into json format and store it in a temp file using the spring integration?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a typo in your code snippet - `transformationSuccessChanel`. It's hard to perform search in such a big domain specific code.

Not sure what is your goal, but that's definitely not a channel responsibility.

For the transformation purpose there is a `<transformer>` in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html

So, if your `<int:service-activator id="requestInjector">` expect a tmp file with the JSON content, you just need to place before that and after `<int:service-activator id="requestTransformer">` a couple those `<transformer>`: one to convert a `payload` to the JSON (the `<object-to-json-transfrormer>` should do the trick for your) and another to create a file with that content. I think for the file it would be better to use a `<int-file:outbound-gateway>` to write a content into the file and get a `java.io.File` as a reply: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-writing.

You can combine all the logic into the `<chain>` also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain

Comment: Intention of the question is that after receiving a message payload on a channel, using spring integration file support I want to convert the received payload into JSON format and and store that in a temp file.

Comment: Hm. I wonder what is wrong with my answer that you didn't find it sufficient... I told you: `<object-to-json-transfrormer>` and `<int-file:outbound-gateway>` before that `requestInjector` service. Or you just don't share with us enough info...